# Firebase Hosting page not refreshed when on iFrame

Tags: firebase, iframe, mobile, refresh

I have a mobile application (ionic 5 cordova Angular 11) with a page that contain an iFrame.

The source of the iFrame is a web page hosted in [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting).

When I modify and publish my web hosted page, if I access the page with it's direct URL, all the changes are done. But when I open my mobile app with the page embed in an iFrame, the changes are not replicated.
I believe there is a kind of cache, but I can't be sure about that, and I don't know how to refresh it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase hosting sites don't always show the latest version by default but use a cached version instead. I managed to solve this problem by creating an inframe linked to a Firebase Hosting site dynamically. When loading the page, the timestamp of the current date & time is added to the source's url. This causes firebase hosting to return the latest version.
Something like this should work:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src =
  "https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/?t=" +
  new Date().valueOf();
document.getElementsByTagName("my-iframe")[0].appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: that is a great way to solve this. Thank you !